# view to controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

view to controller method

```
        .ClientEvents(events =>
        {
            events.OnDataBinding("onDB");
        })
```

Comment: The "insert" method should create a new record on the server, then returns it to the client for editing.  Where do you expect the *UserLogonName* value to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dbaseman said - the insert operation sends the form values which will be used to generate new record with new datakey.
Also the name of the parameter by default is called **id** - in the update action method you could retrieve it like this:

```
[GridAction]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Update(string id)
{
    // code..
    return View();
}
```